# Product of Local Hamiltonians is Local

Tags: quantum-information, locality, spin-models

Let $H_1,H_2$ be local Hamiltonians (i.e. interactions are finite range). Let us form the product of the exponentials of both. By Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff, this defines a third Hamiltonian,

$$e^{H_1}e^{H_2}:=e^{H_3}$$

Can we say that $H_3$ is at least quasi-local (i.e. interactions exponentially decay with distance)?

Comment: I think so. If you write the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula explicitly, the contribution of higher order commutators should decay exponentially.

Comment: Hmm interesting - how would I show this explicitly?